# How to use selectNodes to select a node in XML below?

Tags: xml, dom

How do I select the node "nfeStatusServicoNF2Result"?
I try with the code below but the result of selectNodes is zero.

sample of the code

```
lXMLDoc := CoDOMDocument50.Create;
try
  lXMLDoc.loadXML(lRespose.DataString);

  lXMLDoc.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:n="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2"');

  lXmlNodes := lXMLDoc.selectNodes('n:nfeStatusServicoNF2Result');
  if lXmlNodes.length = 0 then
  begin
    lHostError := '';

    lXmlNodes := lXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName('n:Value');
    if lXmlNodes.length > 0 then
      lHostError := lHostError + lXmlNodes.item[0].text;

    lXmlNodes := lXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName('n:Text');
    if lXmlNodes.length > 0 then
      lHostError := lHostError + lXmlNodes.item[0].text;

    if lHostError = '' then
      lHostError := lRespose.DataString;

    raise Exception.Create(lHostError);
  end else
  begin
    Result := RemoveVersaoXML(lXmlNodes.item[0].text);
  end;
finally
  lXMLDoc := nil;
end;
```

Xml file

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
    <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
      <cUF>31</cUF>
      <versaoDados>2.00</versaoDados>
    </nfeCabecMsg>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <nfeStatusServicoNF2Result xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
      <retConsStatServ xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <verAplic>13_0_96</verAplic>
        <cStat>517</cStat>
        <xMotivo>Rejeicao: Falha no schema XML - inexiste atributo versao na tag raiz da     mensagem</xMotivo>
        <cUF>31</cUF>
        <dhRecbto>2013-08-08T17:45:48</dhRecbto>
      </retConsStatServ>
    </nfeStatusServicoNF2Result>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you have to declare namespace prefixes before you can use them in XPath.

In MSXML this is done by setting the [`SelectionNamespaces` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), like this:

```
var
    lXMLDoc   : IXMLDOMDocument3;
begin
  ...
  lXMLDoc.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', "xmlns:n='http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2'");
  lXMLDoc.selectNodes('//n:nfeStatusServicoNF2Result');
  ...
end;
```

Note that you can choose any prefix you like, but you *must* chose a prefix.

Comment: Length of the nodelist is still zero. I post the complete delphi code above. thank you

Comment: Try again with the modified XPath.

Answer (score 1):

See this article on how to add a namespace resolver to your query:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: I don't think the OP is using JavaScript.

Comment: no problem, any help is very appreciated. because it is the same technology I think

Comment: Oscar, this documentation is very nice, but I think there is a better way to do that. I´ll give ou a point for that answer but what I realy what is to select the node with selectNodes. which is a easy way to do that. Thank you.